# Blank screen pdf displayed in android

Tags: android, itext, itextg

I am using following gradle file for pdf generation:

```
 compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

Since my app has chinese characters,I have added itext-asian.jar file in my classpath.Initially it was giving error 'More than one file was found with OS independent path `'com/itextpdf/text/pdf/fonts/cmap_info.txt'`
So I added this in my gradle:

```
packagingOptions {

    pickFirst 'com/itextpdf/text/pdf/fonts/cmap_info.txt'
}
```

Now gradle is successful,but nothing is displayed in my pdf.Its just a blank screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me,I forgot to add FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyDealActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",new File(path));

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        i.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        return i;
```